# Question based on numbers

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest natural number which can be expressed both as a sum of 7 consecutive numbers and as a sum of  9 consecutive numbers

Kindly explain the logic to solve.

Comment: If a number can be expressed as the sum of 7 consecutive numbers, if the middle number happens to be $x$ then it is $(x-3)+(x-2)+\dots+(x+3)=7x$

Comment: Did you mean to write "queues" instead of "ques"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I am pretty sure he meant that as an abbreviation of "question".

Comment: @suomynonA, I was being sarcastic.  It's pretty obvious that it's a question so the word "question" is unnecessary.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Doesn't sound sarcastic to me...

Comment: Ya you are right. That's question

Answer (score 6):

Let's pretend you are solving this equation. The equations would be $$7x+28=y$$ and $$9z+45=y$$ Since the GCF of the left hand sides of each of the equations would be $7$ and $9$ respectively, you just multiply them together to get your answer of $63$.